# Meaning of flag code "SWTED" of unix process?

Tags: unix

Code of [proc.h](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/src/proc.h.html).

The `S` of `SWTED` probably means `stat`. What about `WTED`? Is it the abbreviation of word `watched`?

Comment: What is the source of this code piece? it is hard to know without context.

Comment: `waited`, just a guess.

Comment: It seems set in `wait()`. http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/src/sys1.c.html

Comment: @Ripple Good one!

Comment: @hk768: This has nothing to do with Linux, so please do remove the `linux` tag. In particular, neither the Linux kernel or the Coreutils userspace tools define `SWTED` or `WTED`. (Yes, I checked them.) This question is limited to whatever system the header file was taken from.

Comment: @NominalAnimal ok

Comment: @hk768: Thank you. I hope you understand my unhappiness: I'm fairly competent with regards to Linux and Linux innards, and the question (the `SWTED` constant in particular) confounded me. I spent a good 15 minutes wondering if there is a huge gaping hole in my knowledge, until I was certain *it had nothing to do with Linux*. I've used SysV7 systems, but never delved into their sources. Having unrelated tags in ones questions may lead to people (who only try to be helpful) wasting quite a bit of their time.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thank you too. And I will tag question more correctly next time I ask question.

Answer (score 3):

In [UNIX 7](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/u7ed/usr/sys/h/proc.h.html#xref:m:SWTED) the SWTED flag is used in two places:

1. [Inside `ptrace()`](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/u7ed/usr/sys/sys/sig.c.html#s:_ptrace), the SWTED flag is cleared before running the child process

   ```
   ptrace()
   {
       ...
       p->p_flag &= ~SWTED;
       setrun(p);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. [Inside `wait()`](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/u7ed/usr/sys/sys/sys1.c.html#s:_wait), if the process is stopped (traced) and the SWTED flag is cleared, then flag will be set, and its PID and signal passed back.

   ```
   wait()
   {
       ...
       if(p->p_stat == SSTOP) {
           if((p->p_flag&SWTED) == 0) {
               p->p_flag |= SWTED;
               u.u_r.r_val1 = p->p_pid;
               u.u_r.r_val2 = (fsig(p)<<8) | 0177;
               return;
           }
           continue;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

That means SWTED is set when a traced process is used in `wait()`, thus most likely meaning **w**ai**ted**. (SWAIT already exists so the name can't be used.)